# Java: Using a double variable to call a double method

Tags: java, methods

The error I'm getting is:

```
"Cannot invoke yearlyPay() on the primitive type double"
```

I'm trying to call the method: `yearlyPay()` on the variable `calcPay`.
I've created `yearlyPay()` and it looks as so:

```
public double yearlyPay(double pay)
{
    double yearlyPay = hourlyRate * HOURS_YEAR;
    System.out.println("public double yearlyPay(double pay): " + yearlyPay);
    System.out.println("");
    return yearlyPay;
}
```

then I have another method where calcPay is located

```
public double localTax(double calcPay)
{
    double pay = calcPay;
    double localTax;

    if (pay.yearlyPay() < 45000)
    {
        localTax = (1.15 / 100) * pay;
    }
    else
        localTax = (1.15 / 100) * 45000;

    return localTax;
}
```

I also figured that having

```
double pay = calcPay
```

is kinda redundant, so I changed it to

```
public double localTax(double calcPay)
{   //removed double pay = calcPay
    double localTax;

    if (calcPay.yearlyPay() < 45000)
    {
        localTax = (1.15 / 100) * pay;
    }
    else
        localTax = (1.15 / 100) * 45000;

    return localTax;
}
```

But...same thing happened.

I googled the problem (with the error message) but I didn't find anything that helped.

There was a place that said to change double to Double, but I didn't know which ones where to change. So I tried each one, one by one...needless to say that didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated. There is more to the code (which is homework). I didn't post it all cuz I don't think it's useful. Ask if you need specific though.

Also if this question is similar to this one, let me know, I'll delete this and look at that one. I probably missed it in the 3,000,000+ search results on google.

Comment: Why have you written `yearlyPay` with a `(double pay)` argument you're not using? You don't seem to be trying to pass in a double when you call it.

Comment: If you want to call `yearlyPay` and pass it `calcPay` you write `yearlyPay(calcPay)`. You're clearly missing some extremely basic java concepts. I'd revisit some beginner tutorials.

Comment: `double` is a primitive type.  It can't have methods.  What class is the method `yearlyPay()` in?

Comment: You were trying to call yearlyPay as a static method on a primitive. What you must do is this: myClass.yearlyPay(calcPay); You must put yearlyPay method into a class and either make an object of that class and call the method on that object or make the class static and call method without creating an object.

Comment: what about giving more meaningful names to your methods... like verbs+Actions alike

Comment: @khelwood - I edited the code and forgot to remove that. But now I need it so I'll keep it.

Comment: @tnw - Thanks! I definitely go back and read some more.

Comment: @SteveSmith my class is called Employee and I'm using it to call the main which is in EmployeeDemo

Comment: @leonz - Thank you! I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ - I use verbAction with accessors to differentiate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only objects have methods.

A `double` is a *primitive* not an object.

Your `yearlyPay()` method is a method of the class you are writing, not of `double`.

So if `yearlyPay()` is defined in the same class as the call, you call it as:

```
double n = yearlyPay(calcPay);
```

... or if you wrote the method in another class (say, `PayCalculator`):

```
PayCalculator payCalculator = new PayCalculator(); 
...
double n = payCalculator.yearlyPay(calcPay);
```

... or if the method is in `PayCalculator` as a `static` method:

```
double n = PayCalculator.yearlyPay(calcPay);
```

---

Incidentally, it's not a good idea to use floating-point number types for money calculations. Google for reasons.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Thank you!